# How to make DropdownButton inside an AlertDialog update the text to selected item in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Basically, after the user taps an Inkwell, the method solicAlert() is called, passing the type of the document. After that, I need to show a dialog in which the user is supposed to pick a Year and click on Ok. But when I select the year on the dropdownbutton, nothing changes in the screen. The option selected as default remains. Any ideas?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  Widget sca = Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Serviços"),
    ),
    body: GridView.count(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 22.0),
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      children: _listDocs.map((value) {
        return Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),

          child: Center(
            child: new InkWell(
              // onTap: () => _solicita(value['document'], value['tipo']),  
              onTap: () {
                if (value['tipo'] == 1 || value['tipo'] == 2) {                    
                  solicAlert(value['tipo']);
                } else {
                  _solicita(value['document'], value['tipo'], []);
                }
              },   
              child: GridTile(
                footer: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  // margin: new EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                  child: Text(
                    value['document'],
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Humanist",
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.blue[900]
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Image.asset(value['image']),
              ),
            )
          )
        );
      }).toList(),
    ),
    drawer: DrawerMenu(),
  );

 // solicAlert method is called to handle whats next

Widget solicAlert(int tipo) {
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    switch (tipo) {
      case 1:
        return formRendimentos();
        break;
      case 2:
        return formHolerite();
        break;
      case 3:
        return _solicita("Declaração de Trabalho", 3, []);
        break;
      case 4:
        return _solicita("Novo Crachá", 4, []);
        break;
    }
  }
);
}


Widget formRendimentos() {

var now = new DateTime.now();
var currentYear = int.parse(DateFormat('yyyy').format(now));
var year1 = currentYear - 1;
var year2 = currentYear - 2;
var year3 = currentYear - 3;

print(currentYear); 

List <String> yearsList = [currentYear.toString(), year1.toString(), year2.toString(), year3.toString()];

String _selectedText = currentYear.toString();
return AlertDialog(
  title: Text("Year of Reference:"),
  content: DropdownButton<String>(
    hint: Text("Pick..."),
    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
    iconSize: 24,
    elevation: 16,
    value: _selectedText,
    onChanged: (String newValue) {
      print('new value: '+ newValue);
      setState(() {
        _selectedText = newValue;
        print("Changed: " + _selectedText);
      });
      dados = [{
          'ano': _selectedText
        }];
    },
    isExpanded: true,
    items: yearsList
      .map((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
  ),       
);
}
```